# Reference request: local volatility and time-dependent volatility

Tags: local-volatility

Is there a good practitioners guide to time-dependent and local volatility models?

Comment: the [opengamma paper](https://developers.opengamma.com/quantitative-research/Local-Volatility-OpenGamma.pdf) on it is okay, and if you want to go farther and use stochastic local vol, this [peter jaeckel paper](http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~kahl/publications/HypHypHooray.pdf) is good.